# How to write optimized queries in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, optimization

Are there any guidelines to write the optimized queries in MySQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Optimizing Queries with EXPLAIN, mysql website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html)

[10 Tips for Optimizing MySQL Queries (That don’t suck)](http://20bits.com/articles/10-tips-for-optimizing-mysql-queries-that-dont-suck/)

[Optimizing MySQL: Queries and Indexes](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/1382791/Optimizing-MySQL-Queries-and-Indexes.htm)

try googling "MySQL optimized queries" , and check dev.mysql.com

Answer (score 1):

[**MySQL 5.5 Reference Manual :: 7 Optimization**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization.html)